# Ordered 2.5g net but LAN is 1gb

Tags: networking, lan, internet-connection

i am in need of help please, i have a cat8 cable plugged into my router by At&t. The network on my laptop says it supports 2.5g. I did a speed test and got 800Mbs, so i changed the mtu to 1500 and now getting 1.2g. But still not 2.5g. I have got all of the latest drivers and my laptop is definitely capable of doing 5g. Im at a loss on what else i can do?

Comment: How are you connected to the router? Why do you think your laptop is "definitely capable of doing 5g"?

Comment: Much more info needed. Cat8 cable plugged into router but you are talking about 5g (wireless)?

Comment: So its plugged into the router and into my Ethernet port, im getting 1300mbps via speed test. Its supposed to be 2500mbps im stuck on how to fix this. My Ethernet port is more than capable of handling 5000mbps via LAN